# Verification of a function call on a mock object not matched when a params array is used

Tags: unit-testing, castle-windsor, moq, windsor-facilities

I have the following test:

```
[Test]
public void VerifyThat_WhenInitializingTheLoggingInterceptionFacility_TheLoggingInterceptorIsAdded()
{
    var kernel = new Mock<IKernel>(MockBehavior.Loose)
            {
                DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock
            };
    kernel.Setup(k => k.AddFacility<LoggingInterceptionFacility>())
                .Returns(kernel.Object)
                .Callback(() => ((IFacility)new LoggingInterceptionFacility()).Init(kernel.Object, Mock.Of<IConfiguration>()));

    kernel.Setup(k => k.Register(It.IsAny<IRegistration[]>()))
                  .Returns(kernel.Object)
                  .Verifiable();

    kernel.Object.AddFacility<LoggingInterceptionFacility>();

    kernel.Verify(k => k.Register(It.Is<IRegistration[]>(r => r.Contains(Component.For<LoggingInterceptor>()))));
}
```

As you can see I am mocking the real behavior of the kernel by calling the facilitiy's `Init(IKernel, IConfiguration)` method which in turns calls the protected `Init()` method.
Here's how the protected Init() looks like:

```
protected override void Init()
{
    Kernel.ProxyFactory.AddInterceptorSelector(new LoggingModelInterceptorsSelector());
    Kernel.Register(Component.For<LoggingInterceptor>());
}
```

I expected that the verification would pass but it does not. If I verify that the Kernel.Register was called at all with `It.IsAny<LoggingInterceptor>()` the test passes.
What am I not matching right here? Is there a way to make this test pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are testing way too much here. You are effectively reimplmenting a lot of Windsor's internals by piping calls from `AddFacility` to `LoggingInterceptionFacility.Init`.

All you **really** need to test is the fact that your facility calls `Register` on the kernel and assume that Windsor does the right thing. After all, it has unit tests of its own ;)

After doing that, the test becomes much more readable, which I consider the most important aspect.

```
[Test]
public void VerifyThat_WhenInitializingTheLoggingInterceptionFacility_TheLoggingInterceptorIsAdded()
{
    var kernel = new Mock<IKernel>();

    kernel.Setup(k => k.Register(It.IsAny<IRegistration[]>()))
                  .Returns(kernel.Object)
                  .Verifiable();
    //Explicit interface implementation requires casting to the interface
    ((IFacility)new LoggingInterceptionFacility()).Init(kernel.Object, Mock.Of<IConfiguration>().Object);
    //verify the type of registration here
    kernel.Verify(k => k.Register(It.Is<IRegistration[]>(r => r[0] is ComponentRegistration<LoggingInterceptor>);
}
```

**EDIT** Calls to `Component.For` return different instances between setup and execution. I updated the code to reflect that and have the verification check the type of the component.

Comment: You are wrong here. First of all You can't call Init(IKernel, IConfiguration) directly. You have to cast to IFacility to do that. Second of all, I am isolating the behavior of windsor here. It doesn't matter if it's written correctly or not and I am using it naturally, like the intended usecase. However I did not know that Component.For returns an object that does not implement == or Equals(). I have mixed feelings about your answer here.

Comment: `Component.For` is a factory and it returns a new instance every time. By default objects are compared by reference, and since they are not immutable value objects, they do not override `Object.Equals` to do value comparison.

Comment: No, all you are testing is that you've reverse engineered Castle Windsor code correctly at the beginning of the test method. If you want a better integration test, treat Castle as a black box, do not mock it, set up your logger and then verify that it actually logs things. That way you verify that the whole solution works.

Comment: Your code did not compile. You cannot pass a Mock<IConfiguration> to Init(). And you got me sold.